# What's the meaning of text-bottom?

Tags: css

Is there anyone tell me how to tell the difference between 'text-bottom' and 'bottom' of 'veritical-align' in CSS. Thank you very much.

Comment: you are forgetting about `line-height`

Comment: yes don't forget line-height, make line-height = font-size and see

Answer (score 2):

It's more obvious if you include an explicit `height` and `line-height`. `text-bottom` will match the bottom of the text, whereas `bottom` will match the bottom of the element.

```css
div {
   display: inline-block;
   font-family: "Arial";
   background-color: blue;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 80px;
}
      
#left .px100 {
   font-size: 100px;
}
      
#left .px50 {
   font-size: 50px;
   vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
      
#right .px100 {
   font-size: 100px;
}
      
#right .px50 {
   font-size: 50px;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
   x
   <span class="px100">x<span>
   <span class="px50">x<span>
</div>
<div id="right">
   x
   <span class="px100">x<span>
   <span class="px50">x<span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

**text-bottom**

> Aligns the bottom of the element with the bottom of the parent element's font.

**bottom**

> Aligns the bottom of the element and its descendants with the bottom of the entire line.